# Experiencing an issue with my while loop

Tags: c#

I would like some advice on where I am going wrong here. The console application displays menu choices and asks the user to enter a valid menu option.

Now it's meant to work so that if the number entered is 1, 2 or 3, it says 'You have chosen option x' then 'Press any key to close' but the program doesn't display the 'You have chosen option x' then 'Press any key to close'. It works though if the number is less than 1 or above 3, saying 'Menu choice not between 1-3' then 'Please re-enter'. Where am I going wrong?

I haven't been doing programming for very long and if I can correct my error this time, I know for the future.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _4._6
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int iChoice = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("1: Add two numbers");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Multiply two numbers");
        Console.WriteLine("3: Exit the program");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice: ");
        iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        while (iChoice < 1 || iChoice > 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Menu choice not between 1-3: ");
            Console.Write("Please re-enter: ");
            iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadKey();

            if  (iChoice > 1 || iChoice < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have chosen option " + iChoice);
                iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.ReadKey();

            }



        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The best thing you can do is learn to use the debugger. Then you can step through the code and see what is happening.

Comment: the code in your while loop executing only if iChoice is NOT is [1..3]? In that case, iChoice will never be in the condition specified by your if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner if can never be entered because it contradicts the condition of the outer if:

Change it like this

```
    while (iChoice < 1 || iChoice > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Menu choice not between 1-3: ");
        Console.Write("Please re-enter: ");
        iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }


    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen option " + iChoice);
```

Also note that the condition of the second if in your code is wrong

Comment: After running this code, the line "iChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());" is highlighted, saying FormatException was unhandled - Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

If block should be out of while block. Because your while block wont run your if block if condition is false. Which means you're not allowing your if block to check it's condition

Answer (score 0):

You assign to `iChoice` in two places in the code. Maybe it's less confusing to say:

```
    Console.WriteLine("1: Add two numbers");
    Console.WriteLine("2: Multiply two numbers");
    Console.WriteLine("3: Exit the program");

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your choice:");

    int iChoice;
    while (true)
    {
      int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iChoice);
      if (iChoice >= 1 && iChoice <=3)
        break; // choice is OK

      Console.WriteLine("Menu choice not between 1-3.");
      Console.Write("Please re-enter:");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen option " + iChoice);
    // ...
```

Note: I just changed `Convert.ToInt32` into `int.TryParse`. The advantage is that if the user types something which is not a number, like "sdfih", it will just make `iChoice` zero instead of crashing the application.

Comment: TryParse returns a bool indicating if the parsing succeeded. Don't check of iChoice is zero, but rather, check that TryParse returns true.

Comment: @BAF Yes, in the general case, one could say something like `if (parsed && iChoice >= 1 && iChoice <=3)` where `parsed` is the boolean return value of `int.TryParse`, but in this case, because `0` is not a legal value anyway, one can be sloppy and just check the `out` parameter. The `out` parameter is guaranteed to be `0` whenever the try-parse fails (returns `false`).